# Como Utilizar um UPDATE dentro de IF ELSE SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou tentando verificar se uma coluna existe dentro de uma determinada tabela.

Ao verificar se existe, quero atualizar a coluna com o valor 1, se não, criar e atualizar.

Porém, toda vez que executo ocorre o erro de que a coluna ainda não existe.

No ciclo de execução, ele considera primeiro meu update ao alter table.

Para exemplificar o que estou tentando fazer:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM BANCO_DE_DADOS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE (TABLE_NAME) = 'MinhaTabela' 
            AND  (COLUMN_NAME) = 'CodZona'  )  

BEGIN
update BANCO_DE_DADOS..MinhaTabela set CodZona = 1 where CodZona < 1 or CodZona is null

END

ELSE

BEGIN 

ALTER TABLE BANCO_DE_DADOS..MinhaTabela
ADD  [CodZona] [int] NULL

update BANCO_DE_DADOS..MinhaTabela set CodZona = 1

END
```

Erro:

```
Mensagem 207, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 7
Nome de coluna 'CodZona' inválido.
Mensagem 207, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 7
Nome de coluna 'CodZona' inválido.
```

Comment: Se está dando erro é pq essa tabela não existe no seu banco de dados...

Answer (score 0):

Após o `ALTER TABLE` não vai funcionar realizar o `UPDATE`, segue uma alternativa que pode te auxiliar, como no meu exemplo abaixo:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB.dbo.#MinhaTabela') IS NOT NULL 
drop table #MinhaTabela
go 
create table #MinhaTabela (id int) 

insert into #MinhaTabela values(1)
go 

select * from #MinhaTabela go 

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TempDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name like '%MinhaTabela%' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Cod')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE #MinhaTabela ADD Cod int;
END

select * from #MinhaTabela go

exec sp_executesql N'update a set a.Cod = 1 from #MinhaTabela a where (a.Cod < 1 or a.Cod is null);'

select * from #MinhaTabela go
```

Answer (score -1):

Coloque o ALTER TABLE como SQL dinâmico no bloco ELSE.

```
EXEC sp_executeSQl N'ALTER TABLE BANCO_DE_DADOS..MinhaTabela ADD  [CodZona] [int] NULL'
```

Answer (score -3):

Creio que vc deva realizar o seu alter table dentro do if mesmo, não precisa realizar um else para isso, veja:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM BANCO_DE_DADOS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MinhaTabela' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'CodZona'
)
BEGIN
    -- Adicione a coluna CodZona se ela não existir
    ALTER TABLE BANCO_DE_DADOS.dbo.MinhaTabela
    ADD [CodZona] [int] NULL

    -- Atribua o valor padrão para a nova coluna
    UPDATE BANCO_DE_DADOS.dbo.MinhaTabela
    SET CodZona = 1
END

-- Agora, mesmo que a coluna já exista, você pode atualizá-la para garantir que os valores sejam >= 1 ou nulos
UPDATE BANCO_DE_DADOS.dbo.MinhaTabela
SET CodZona = 1
WHERE CodZona < 1 OR CodZona IS NULL
```

Answer (score -3):

```
IF not EXISTS( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE (TABLE_NAME) = 'MinhaTabela' 
            AND  (COLUMN_NAME) = 'CodZona'  )  

BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE MinhaTabela ADD [CodZona] int  NULL;
END
GO

update MinhaTabela set CodZona = 1 where CodZona < 1 or CodZona is null
```